# Find hex values in string and replace them

Tags: c#, interop

I am importing powerpoint presentation to my editor using `Microsoft.Office.Interop`. Then i modify the content and create the new ppt using it.
While reading the shape of slide object from power point, some textobject have hex values in it. which creates the problem when i try to import them to my editor.

```
page.Xml.Add(XElement.Parse(string.Format(@strXml)));
```

here strXml contents some hex characters. and i get the exception `' ', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character`. and its different every time due to occurrence of various hex codes in different slide text object. How can i find those hex values and replace(or remove if its not gonna create the problem when final ppt media is created)

Comment: See this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/10/04/xmlserializer-and-invalid-xml.aspx).